# jquery datatable - state save not working for first time

Tags: datatables, state-saving

We are using the [jquery datatable](http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/state_save.html) for the table to save the state. Its not working for the first time, but it works fine next time. We need to retain the filter and paging even after the page refresh, but its not working for the first time. Below is the code we are using for the datatable:

```
$('#Accounts').dataTable({
     "bStateSave": true,
     "aaSorting": [[3, "asc"]], 
     "iDisplayLength": 100
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i also faced this issue and got solution by comparing a slight url difference.
so check your url it require to match with same case. and it will solve your issue